# How to call a method only once in the first page load in the master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, page-lifecycle, ispostback

I have the following case:

`Page1.aspx` this page has the master page `master.aspx`.

I have some code in the master page :

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                adjustServiceBar();

            }
```

when i click any button in the `Page1.aspx`it enters the `!Page.IsPostBack` and execute the method !!

i want this method in the `!Page.IsPostBack)` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to set a session variable and then check that variable to ensure your code will fire only once.
Another way is to set a hidden control on your form and play with its text or value property.

According to each scenario the solution may be very complex such as custom derived masterpages and pages that extend the current events functionality to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is more consistent to check for `IsPostBack` in content page. You can move this condition to `Page1.aspx` and expose `adjustServiceBar()` method in your master page, so that content pages can call it, like `Master.adjustServiceBar()`.

Comment: +1 I would do this too. Afterall the content page is the one posting back not the masterpage.

Comment: `Master.adjustServiceBar();` is Unaccessable due to protection level

Comment: So why don't you change the protection level?) If this is impossible for any reason, you can add another method wrapping this one. Or you can't change master page code at all?

Comment: `public void adjustServiceBar()`

Comment: but still the same issue !

Comment: Did you add MasterType directive to your content page? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228274(v=vs.100).aspx